# incompatible marshal file format (can't be read) format version 4.8 required; 0.0 given

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am getting the following error:

```
incompatible marshal file format (can't be read)
format version 4.8 required; 0.0 given
```

On this line:

```
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all",
```

From this portion of my layouts file:

```
  <html>
    <head>
      <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
      <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all",
                                             "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
      <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
      <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
```

I have never encountered this problem before and the explanations online were either too advanced for me or were related to people making games, my project is a simple rails app that I just started yesterday.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried clearing assets?
`bundle exec rake assets:clean`

And then recompile:
`bundle exec rake assets:precompile`

Are you somehow mixing up Ruby versions? Maybe you are precompiling with 1.9 and running Rails through Passenger or something with 2.0?

Answer (score 4):

Fix: change the secret key base to invalidate all sessions, especially after Rails upgrade.

Comment: A similar solution you can use in development is deleting your cookies

Answer (score 3):

I had to delete the sass and sprockets folders in rails_root/tmp/cache.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I’ll put it here just in case.

I had the similar problem after power outage on my dev machine. Refined solutions, listed around (explicit assets clearing and even removal of `tmp/cache` folder,) did not work for me.

What worked, was a hammer blow:

```
rm -rf $RAILS_ROOT/tmp
```

Make sure that $RAILS_ROOT is defined before doing this, or you will delete your root /tmp directory